# ModuleNotFoundError from Visual Studio after installing Python modules with "pip" on the command line

Tags: python, module, path, pip

I am trying to install modules like `tkinter`, `bs4` and `numpy`.

I use `cmd` and `pip` to install them, and it says that everything is installed fine.

When I am using Visual Studio code it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '....'
```

How can I find out if Python and the modules are in the same PATH?
Or what can i do to fix that?

I've tried to reinstall Python, but I get the same error.

Is it just the VSC?

```
File "c:/Users/Γιώργος Μαργα/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: Have you install pip while installing python or no?

Comment: Is it working without visual studios like in terminal or powershell?

Comment: This might be because VSCODE is using a virtualenv, check the version of python to which you installed your modules and the python version on which VSCODE is running (bottom of the editor) [Python Version on VSCODE](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter)

Comment: @CoolCloud For some reason i can't follow these steps because the small window that says about the new environment doesnt pop on me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so i uninstall python and installed it again but this time i checked the box that said add that to PATH or someithng like this.
I also uninstalled python from the windowsstore however when it ry to run a code in VSC it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

`pip install` is most likely installing globally into a Python interpreter that is different than the one that you have selected in VS Code.

if vscode not recognize your modules try to reload vscode.

install modules with

```
 python3 -m pip install {new_module}
```

and then reload your Vs code
make sure to set your Python interpreter within VSCode to the same as the one in your system path   [pythoninvscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter)

Comment: Honeslty, i am really confused i cant follow these steps because the small window with the new env doesnt pop on me